# how to select nested key if key is unknown

Tags: json, jq

I have a very simple JSON like this:

```
{
   "status":"DOWN",
   "FTPService":{
      "status":"UP"
   },
   "mail":{
      "status":"UP",
      "location":"somehost.example.com:-1"
   },
   "diskSpace":{
      "status":"UP",
      "total":2000396742656,
      "free":1213046730752,
      "threshold":10485760
   },
   "db":{
      "status":"DOWN",
      "database":"Oracle",
      "schema":"foo"
   },
   "refreshScope":{
      "status":"UP"
   }
}
```

Keys "mail", "diskspace", "db" etc. are unknown and could have any name.

I'd like to print all object whose status in not "UP" if the overall status is not "UP".  The desired example output would be

```
"db":{
      "status":"DOWN",
      "database":"Oracle",
      "schema":"foo"
   },
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select those whose status is DOWN. `with_entries` is there to retain original structure.

```
with_entries(select(.value.status? == "DOWN"))
```